# Isolate JSON String in HTTP Reponse from other data

Tags: java, json

I query a PHP script on the server returning some php echos.

The snippet below is a JSON Fragment:

```
 {"cid":"212"}
```

The whole output has some HTML fragments

```
<br>Order posted 214 - 192.168.1.22:4444 <br>{"cid":"214"}
```

What is the easiest way to filter the JSON part out of the rest ?

I know that it would be easier to kill all the other output, but still I would love to find a quick solution for this scenario.

Comment: In the code above, what do you consider the "JSON part"? Or put differently: show us the *whole* response and tell us *what part* you want to extract.

Comment: <br>Order posted 214 - 192.168.1.22:4444 <br>{"cid":"214"}

the part in the {}

Comment: you can use `java` `regex`

Comment: you maybe absolutly right with that ;) since my regex skills are limited could you provide a regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the idea with the regex

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find())
      {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));                                  
      }
```